# Removing specific duplicate values from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame that consists of a lot of ID numbers in one column and a dummy variable in the other column. The data frame has multiple iterations of the same ID, but the dummy values are inconsistent. For example:

```
   ID dummy
1  1111     1
2  1111     1
3  1111     0
4  1112     0
5  1112     0
6  1112     0
7  1112     0
8  1113     1
9  1113     0
10 1113     1
```

What I want is to get my own data frame of all these individual ID numbers as well as the dummy value of 1 (if it ever has a single instance of 1, otherwise just 0). What keeps happening is when I try and separate the duplicates, sometimes I am left with the dummy value that is 0 and not 1. Here is an example of what I am trying to get:

```
   ID dummy
1  1111     1
2  1112     0
3  1113     1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(dummy1=max(dummy)) %>% filter(row_number()==1) %>%
       #dplyr::distinct(ID, .keep_all=T) %>%  #Another option
       select(-dummy1)


    # A tibble: 3 x 2
    # Groups:   ID [3]
      ID dummy
      <int> <int>
1  1111     1
2  1112     0
3  1113     1
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="
               ID dummy
    1  1111     1
    2  1111     1
    3  1111     0
    4  1112     0
    5  1112     0
    6  1112     0
    7  1112     0
    8  1113     1
    9  1113     0
    10 1113     1
                                     ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: There are a few things you can improve/fix. Why do you define `dummy1`, it's not necessary here. Instead of `filter(row_number()==1)` you can use `slice(1)` which is shorter. Lastly it's better/shorter to use `df %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = T)` instead of `df %>% group_by(ID) + slice(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just

```
df[!duplicated(df$ID), ]
#    ID dummy
#1 1111     1
#4 1112     0
#8 1113     1
```

This removes all duplicated `ID`s in a top-down way.

Comment: I've been trying this however it has still given me some problems.

Comment: @hanz you need to be more specific. It’s giving you problems how? This works on the sample data you provide.

Comment: Actually this did end up working. I found a bug in my code and fixed it. Both of these work, but this one was more appealing to the eye.

Comment: @hanz please note if you have a 1 in the 2nd row and 0 in the 1st row within the same ID, you will get the 0, not the 1.

Comment: @hanz This gives identical results as with `dplyr::group_by(ID)` with `dplyr::filter(row_number()==1)` (instead of `filter(row_number() == 1)` a shorter form is to use `slice(1)`). Either way I recommend using the more succinct `duplicated`.